# Help needed for gazebo simulation record

Tags: gazebo, simulation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everyone:
Did anyone of you try to record a gazebo simulation into a video?
The only instructions available is
[https://alliance.seas.upenn.edu/~meam620/wiki/index.php?n=Roslab.RecordingSimulations](https://alliance.seas.upenn.edu/%7Emeam620/wiki/index.php?n=Roslab.RecordingSimulations)

following it, I installed glc-capture but still I have no idea of how to record a simulation.
the format of the command should be:
./glc-capture [capture option]... [application] [application argument]... but for gazebo, I don't know how to fill in the [application]

Any help is appreciated.

Yucong

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31817/help-needed-for-gazebo-simulation-record/) by [yclin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2148/yclin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2012-04-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To record using glc-capture, launch gazebo prefixed by glc-capture, for example if starting gazebo in commandline, use

```
glc-capture gazebo empty.world
```

Or add `launch-prefix="glc-capture"` attribute to the rosnode that starts gazebo.

alternatively, you can also try recordmydesktop

```
sudo apt-get install recordmydesktop
```

---

Originally posted by [john](https://answers.ros.org/users/16/john/) with karma: 86 on 2012-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5